# NSNumberFormatter issue with numberFromString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

I have a category on NSString with this method:

```
-(NSNumber *)numberValue
{
    if (!nfStr)
    {
        nfStr = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    }

    NSLocale *current = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];

    [nfStr setLocale:current];
    [nfStr setDecimalSeparator:[current objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]];
    [nfStr setGroupingSeparator:[current objectForKey:NSLocaleGroupingSeparator]];

    return [nfStr numberFromString:self];
}
```

My current locale is it-IT (decimal separator: "," grouping separator: ".")

when I use stringFromNumber with NSNumber 90000 the NumberFormatter return a correctly formatted string "90.000"

when in a textfield I write the string "90.000" the NumberFormatter return nil instead of NSNumber 90000

why?

Thanks

edit:
textfield delegate

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  myObject.r.qtaOm = [Trim(textField.text) numberValue];
}
```

Comment: Can you post code how you are using it with textfield ?

Comment: posted, is the textfield delgate

Comment: It works for me even with textfield - what is Trim macro - maybe try without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the [NumberStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setNumberStyle%3a) on the formatter.

```
[nfStr setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
```

You can use:

```
enum {
   NSNumberFormatterNoStyle = kCFNumberFormatterNoStyle,
   NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle = kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle,
   NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle = kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle,
   NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle = kCFNumberFormatterPercentStyle,
   NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle = kCFNumberFormatterScientificStyle,
   NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle = kCFNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Lools like your string format is not correctcorrect because numberfromstring method accept string and then returns number but in your case 90.000 is not a valid string it seems
So try passing like that and check

```
 NSString *num=@"90.000";
```

And then check it should work.